# Neatest way to get a distinct list of phone numbers (without removing original formatting)?

Tags: .net, collections, deduplication

We have a master `Person` record and one (or more) duplicate `Persons` and we are merging their data, prioritising the master over the duplicate(s).

When it comes to phone numbers the goal is to merge their data, with a single phone number going into the `Phone` field and any other phone numbers going into a notes field (so as not to discard them completely). Records may or may not contain a phone number.

For neatness we don't want to add to the notes field a bunch of numbers which are basically the same. So we don't want the field to contain:

`(1234) 123123`
`1234 123123`

This would be easy if we could just discard the formatting and spaces but we need to retain those (except for white space on the beginning/end).

We started by creating a Structure (not sure why we have a Structure versus a Class, but anyway)

```
Friend Structure PhoneNumber

Private _Raw As String
Public Property Raw() As String
    Get
        Return _Raw
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Raw = value
    End Set
End Property


Private _Stripped As String
Public Property Stripped() As String
    Get
        Return _Stripped
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Stripped = value
    End Set
End Property


Sub New(ByVal num As String)
    Raw = num
    Dim RegexObj As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^\d]")
    Stripped = RegexObj.Replace(num, "")
    MsgBox(num & vbCrLf & Stripped)

End Sub
End Structure
```

Then, the merge code looks like this:

```
    Dim phones As New List(Of PhoneNumber)
    If master.Phone.Trim.Length > 1 Then
        phones.Add(New PhoneNumber(master.Phone.Trim))
    End If
    For Each x As Person In duplicates
        If x.Phone.Trim.Length > 1 And Not phones.Contains(New PhoneNumber(x.Phone.Trim)) Then
            phones.Add(New PhoneNumber(x.Phone.Trim))
        End If
    Next
    If phones.Count > 0 Then
        master.Phone = phones(0).Raw
    End If
    For i = 1 To phones.Count - 1
        master.Notes &= vbCrLf & "Alt. Phone: " & phones(i).Raw
    Next
```

But, obviously, the problem here is it's allowing the duplicates.

We kind of want the `Contains` to match on "stripped" values only, but of course it doesn't know to do that.

This already seems like too much code for such a minor feature, but at the moment we're looking at writing something (in the Structure?) that will replace the `Contains` and match on stripped only. Is there a neater way?

Code is in VB, but C# answers welcome.

Remember too that we have to *prioritise* the master, so if we use LINQ and Distinct we need to ensure we don't lose the sort order (that's my understanding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a better way to do this was to use a `Dictionary`. That way we can do without the Structure and use Dictionary lookups on both the Key (the stripped phone number) and the Value (the formatted original).

Something like this:

```
    Dim RegexObj As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^\d]")
    Dim phones As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    master.Phone = master.Phone.Trim
    If master.Phone.Length > 1 Then
        phones.Add(RegexObj.Replace(master.Phone, ""), master.Phone)
    End If
    For Each x As Person In duplicates
        x.Phone = x.Phone.Trim
        If x.Phone.Length > 1 And Not phones.ContainsKey(RegexObj.Replace(x.Phone, "")) Then
            phones.Add(RegexObj.Replace(x.Phone, ""), x.Phone)
        End If
    Next
    If phones.Count > 0 Then
        master.Phone = phones.First.Value
        phones.Remove(phones.First.Key)
    End If
    For Each entry As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In phones
        master.Notes &= IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(master.Notes.Trim), "", vbCrLf).ToString _
            & "Alt. Phone: " & entry.Value
    Next
```